# How to set custom Adapter for the cell of Caldroid Fragment in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have created a custom adapter for Caldroid cell by extending the `CaldroidAdapter` class. But I don't know how to set that adapter to Caldroid fragment. This is my adapter class. Where should I call this class in `MainActivity` in which I have created Caldroid fragment?

```
public class CaldroidAdapter extends CaldroidGridAdapter {
    public CaldroidAdapter(Context context, int month, int year, Map caldroidData, Map extraData) {
        super(context, month, year, caldroidData, extraData);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View cellview = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            cellview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calender, null);
        }

        int topPadding = cellview.getPaddingTop();
        int leftPadding = cellview.getPaddingLeft();
        int bottomPadding = cellview.getPaddingBottom();
        int rightPadding = cellview.getPaddingRight();

        TextView txt_custom = (TextView) cellview.findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
        txt_custom.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        DateTime datetime = this.datetimeList.get(position);
        Resources resource = context.getResources();

        boolean shouldresetDisableView;
        if (datetime.getMonth() != month) {

            txt_custom.setTextColor(resource.getColor(com.caldroid.R.color.cell_text_color_dark));

            shouldresetDisableView = false;
            boolean shouldResetSelectedView = false;

            if ((minDateTime != null && datetime.lt(minDateTime)) || (maxDateTime != null && datetime.gt(maxDateTime)) || (disableDates != null && disableDates.indexOf(datetime) != -1))
                ;
            txt_custom.setTextColor(CaldroidFragment.disabledTextColor);
            if (CaldroidFragment.disabledBackgroundDrawable == -1) {
                cellview.setBackgroundResource(com.caldroid.R.drawable.disable_cell);
            } else {
                cellview.setBackgroundResource(CaldroidFragment.disabledBackgroundDrawable);
            }

            if (datetime.equals(getToday())) {
                cellview.setBackgroundResource(com.caldroid.R.drawable.red_border_gray_bg);
            }
        } else {
            shouldresetDisableView = true;
        }
        if (selectedDates != null && selectedDates.indexOf(datetime) != -1) {
            cellview.setBackgroundResource(resource
                    .getColor(com.caldroid.R.color.caldroid_sky_blue));
            txt_custom.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            shouldresetDisableView = true;
        }

        if (shouldresetDisableView && shouldresetDisableView) {

            if (datetime.equals(getToday())) {
                cellview.setBackgroundResource(com.caldroid.R.drawable.red_border);
            } else {
                cellview.setBackgroundResource(com.caldroid.R.drawable.cell_bg);
            }
        }

        txt_custom.setText("" + datetime.getDay());
        cellview.setPadding(leftPadding, rightPadding, topPadding, bottomPadding);
        setCustomResources(datetime, cellview, txt_custom);
        return cellview;
    }
}
```

Comment: Resolved the this problem

Comment: can you please post your solution.